# Multiple databases with MongoRepository

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongorepository

I'm using Mongo Repository to talk to a mongo database.

Here is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <!-- See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Connectionstrings for more info -->
   <add name="MongoServerSettings" connectionString="mongodb://myDomain:27017/myDatabase1" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I then use it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoRepository;

class Program
{
    static MongoRepository<Customer> customerrepo = new MongoRepository<Customer>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Add customers
        var john = new Customer() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
        var jane = new Customer() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" };
        var jerry = new Customer() { FirstName = "Jerry", LastName = "Maguire" };
        customerrepo.Add(new[] { john, jane, jerry });
    }
}
```

This works fine. But how can I configure it so it can talk to 2 or more databases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MongoRepository<T>` class has a constructor that takes a connection string or a mongo url as parameter.

If you want a repository on myDatabase2 just instante a MongoRepository with the correct connection string. Ex:

```
var customerRepoOnDb2 = new MongoRepository<Customer>("mongodb://myServer/myDatabase2");
```

You can add the connection string to your config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MongoServerSettings" connectionString="mongodb://myDomain:27017/myDatabase1" />
  <add name="MongoServerSettings2" connectionString="mongodb://..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

And:

```
var customerRepoOnDb2 = new MongoRepository<Customer>(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoServerSettings2"].ConnectionString);
```